# POSTGRES - put TEXT as condition through "IN" clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have problem to create function with following definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COPY_ACTIONS_V1_TEST(iActionMasterIdList IN text)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE

    vRequestedId ACTIONS.ACTION_ID%TYPE;
    result_aid_list TEXT;

    cur_action CURSOR FOR 
        select act.ACTION_ID
        FROM   ACTIONS act
        WHERE  1=1
        and act.action_id IN iActionMasterIdList;
        
BEGIN 
        OPEN cur_action;
        LOOP
            FETCH cur_action INTO vActionMasterId;
            if not FOUND THEN
                return result_aid_list;
            end if;
   
        END LOOP; 
        CLOSE cur_action;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to pass text variable as '123,124,126' to this function and I want to search for this ids in table. I tried many options like:

1. act.action_id = any(string_to_array(iActionMasterIdList))
2. act.action_id = any('{' || iActionMasterIdList || '}')

But nothing works. Each throws different error. I am not expert in postgres, can you give advice?

Thank you

Comment: You should pass an array directly, not a comma-separated string. Additionally: the cursor and the LOOP are totally unnecessary. This can be replaced with a single SELECT statement in a `language sql` function.

Comment: `select '123' = any(string_to_array( '123,124,126', ',' )) t`. You are missing the delimiter argument `','` per [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html): *string_to_array ( string text, delimiter text [, null_string text ] ) → text[]*

Comment: Why did you make it so complex? There is no need for a cursor and no need for plpgsql.

Comment: @FrankHeikens example was just "shortened code" , in real case plpg sql was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string_to_array` - returns array elements in text type. If `action_id` is integer, then you can use casting types. Example:

```
and act.action_id::text = any(string_to_array(iActionMasterIdList, ','))
```

Comment: Sorry , I had an mistype in condition.
I need: and act.action_id IN iActionMasterIdList;

It looks, that your code does not behave this way, or?

Comment: @MartinFedyFedorko  `IN` is equivalent to `= ANY`